# Python function decorator should print full method name

Tags: python, python-3.x, decorator, introspection

The following useful decorator measures the execution time of a function. It also prints the function's name. However, it would be great if it could also print the class name if the function is a method. What is a concise way to get to the full method name a la `Class.method`?

```
import time

def timeit(f):

    def timed(*args, **kw):

        ts = time.time()
        result = f(*args, **kw)
        te = time.time()

        print('func:%r args:[%r, %r] took: %2.4f sec' % (f.__name__, args, kw, te-ts))
        return result

    return timed
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What about `.__qualname__` ?

```
In [1]: class MyClass(object):
   ...:     def my_method(self):
   ...:         pass
   ...:

In [2]: MyClass.my_method.__qualname__
Out[2]: 'MyClass.my_method'
```

Comment: useful! but available only since Python 3.3 https://docs.python.org/3.6/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=qualname#definition.__qualname__

Answer (score 1):

There may be a better way, but in Python 2 (which doesn't have `__qualname__`)  you can use

```
m.im_class.__name__
```

as in

```
>>> class MyClass(object):
...   def foo(self):
...      pass
... 
>>> m = MyClass.foo
>>> print m.im_class.__name__ + '.' + m.__name__
MyClass.foo
```